# Joining Two or More Views in MySQL

Tags: mysql, join, view

I have two views,

```
View one: company_id, company_name,countA
View Two: company_id, Company_name, CountB
```

I want to join those two views into a new view but the result set I needed to be as follows:

```
company_id, company_name, countA,countB.
```

I did research and I tried joins and merges but I cannot figure it out. Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try like this:

```
select view1.company_id, view1.company_name, view1.countA,view2.countB
from view1 inner join view2 on view1.company_id = view2.company_id
```

Comment: It worked. I had to recreate my views because my column names where the same and I was trying to define them based on the tables. Thank You for your help.

Answer (score 0):

if you want rows from both views be included, you should use full outer join which is not available in mysql. though there is some roundabouts:

```
SELECT view1.company_id, view1.company_name,countA,countB
FROM view1 LEFT JOIN view2 ON view1.company_id = view2.company_id
UNION
SELECT view2.company_id, view2.company_name,countA,countB
FROM view1 RIGHT JOIN view2 ON view1.company_id = view2.company_id
WHERE view1.company_id IS NULL
```